# arrays / pointers (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

in C is:
`*(array)` equivalent to `array[0]`?

Therefore is 
`*(array+2)` equivalent to `array[2]`?

Comment: See also the "Arrays and Pointers" section of the C FAQ list: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, for instance:

given:

```
int a[10];
```

Then

```
*(a + 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
a[2]
```

and just for good measure.

```
a[2]
```

is equivalent to

```
2[a]
```

Comment: OK, you lost me. How can 2[a] = a[2]?

Comment: Yup storage address 2 plus addres of "a" is the same as address of "a" plus 2!

Comment: I had a boss that called that "arraying through and index"... :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this, for more help:
http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html

> 4) Taking a subscript with value i is
>   equivalent 
>          to the operation: "pointer-add i and then 
>          type-dereference the sum", i.e.
>
> ```
>       xxx[i] = *(xxx # i)
> ```

As others mentioned, the answer is yes, but you may want to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: Yes.

Comment: The simple comment is: Useless without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.  (Padding to required 15 character length.)